# How to create a class to store an Object List and display in the JSP without deleting the list?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

Good night, I'm learning **JAVA WEB + JSP + SERVLETS** and as I'm new to both I have the following problems:

I am using the **MVC architecture** to create the models, views and controllers of my application.

My application works as follows:
In the same route I should make **CRUD** from a shopping list, for this I have two classes in two different packages which are:

**Models - Products.java
Services - Shopping.java**

In the Products class I use to instantiate a new item with the code, name and quantity of the product, then with the Purchases I use to store a List of these products and be able to use it in my JSP ...

**The question is:**

**1)** How do I create a List of these instantiated objects and do the methods of the code below?

**2)** How do I display this list in my JSP ..

**3)** How do I do the POST of the form without updating the page, and at the same time my list of products is not erased?

**4)** How do I import classes from other packages into my servlet?

**Compras.java**

```
   public class Compras {
    private List<Object> listaProdutos = new List<Object>();

    public Compras(List<Object> listaProdutos){
        this.listaProdutos = listaProdutos;
    }

    //Adds a new product to the List
    private addProduct(){}

    //Removes a specific product from the list
    private removeSpecificProduct(){}

    //Get all products from the list
    private getAllProducts(){}

    //Get a specific product from the list
    private getSpecificProduct(){}

    // Take the size of the list
    private getListSize(){}

    //Change the position of a specific product in the list
    private changeSpecificProductPosition(){}

}
```

**Produtos.java**

```
public class Produtos {
    private int quantity;
    private String name;

    public Produtos(int quantity, String name){
        this.quantity = quantity;
        this.name = name;
    } 
}
```

**Servlets - Add.java**

```
@WebServlet(name = "Add", urlPatterns = {"/Add"})
public class Add extends HttpServlet {

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        // REQUEST PRODUCT
        String productName = request.getParameter("productName").toUpperCase();
        int productQuantity = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("productQuantity"));

        // NEW PRODUCT
        Product newProduct = new Product(productName, productQuantity);

    }

}
```

**JSP**

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <h1><strong>Lista de Compras</strong></h1>
            <hr>
            <div></div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <h1>INCLUSÃO DE UM NOVO ITEM</h1>
            <form action="/add" method="POST" style="background-color: dimgray; padding: 10px;">
                <div style="padding: 5px">
                    <label style="color: white;"><strong>Item:</strong></label> 
                    <input name="productName" type="text" required></input>
                </div>
                <hr>
                <br>
                <div>
                    <label style="color: white;"><strong>Quantidade:</strong></label>
                    <input name="productQuantity" type="number" min="1" required></input
                </div>
                <hr>
                <div style="padding-top: 30px;">
                    <button type="submit">ADICIONAR</button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: _"How do I do the POST of the form without updating the page, and at the same time my list of products is not erased?"_ What is the function of the form?  What does the form show? What is it posting?

Comment: The form's function is to add a new item .. When it clicks the submit button on this form it should go to the servlet to create a new objet add there is an already existing list and return the list information in the JSP

Comment: There are lot of questions you are asking. You have to do some things first (at least try) and look for answers as you do your work. For starters: `Compras.java` is incomplete Java code and it doesn't compile. You are expecting someone to write simple Java code for you. What is the idea?

Comment: Here is a link to [tutorials/examples to writing servlets and jsp](http://pdf.coreservlets.com/). Please look at relevant chapters related to your application to find some answers. _Also_, you can _search the web_ (Google) with questions like "How do I display a list in my JSP", and you  will find quite a few answers already there.

Comment: Similarly you can try searching for ""How do I import classes from other packages".